# Ansible nested definition and reference issues

Tags: ansible

I have a problem with implementing Ansible nested reference YAML variable file.

Example of user dictionary file variable:

1. User dictionary file variable, `dev_infra_bastion_0_example_com` is node FQDN name

   ```sh
   # user varialbe file
   root@dev-infra-bastion-0:~/ansible-stats# hostname
   dev-infra-bastion-0.example.com
   ```

   *vars/user.yml*

   ```yaml
   dev_infra_bastion_0_example_com:
     admin:
       - admin1
       - admin2
       - admin3
     people:
       - peopl1
       - peopl2
       - peopl3
   ```
2. I want to pass the dictionary defined in the *vars/user.yml* file after parsing through this playbook

   ```yaml
   ## create hosts user
   - hosts: test1
     become: yes
     vars_files:
       - vars/user.yml

     pre_tasks:
     - name: debug
       debug:
         msg: "{{ ansible_nodename.replace('-','_').replace('.','_') }}"
       register: mess

     - name: debug mess
       debug:
         msg: "{{ mess }}"
   ```
3. Run info

   ```
   PLAY [test1] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

   TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
   ok: [10.1.204.100] => {
       "msg": "dev_infra_bastion_0_example_com"
   }

   TASK [debug mess] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
   ok: [10.1.204.100] => {
       "msg": {
           "changed": false,
           "failed": false,
           "msg": "dev_infra_bastion_0_example_com"       #Here,Should be a dictionary,but it's string
       }
   }

   PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
   10.1.204.100               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

   debug ------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.10s
   debug mess -------------------------------------------------------------- 0.06s
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two to three things wrong in your playbook.

1. Do not use a `debug` and `register` if you want to register a variable, use the appropriate [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/set_fact_module.html) module

   ```yaml
   - set_fact:
       mess: "{{ ansible_nodename.replace('-','_').replace('.','_') }}"
   ```
2. If you want to access a variable from a variable, you need to either use the [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/vars.html).

   ```yaml
   - debug:
       var: lookup('vars', mess)
   ```
3. Bonus: to replace multiple characters by an underscore, maybe a [`regex_replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) could be nicer, so, you can really do it in a single task:

   ```yaml
   - debug:
       var: lookup('vars', ansible_nodename | regex_replace('[\.-]', '_'))
   ```

---

An example playbook would be:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: lookup('vars', ansible_nodename | regex_replace('[\.-]', '_'))
      vars:
        ansible_nodename: dev-infra-bastion-0.example.com
        dev_infra_bastion_0_example_com:
          admin:
            - admin1
            - admin2
            - admin3
          people:
            - peopl1
            - peopl2
            - peopl3
```

Which would yield the recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  lookup('vars', ansible_nodename | regex_replace('[\.-]', '_')):
    admin:
    - admin1
    - admin2
    - admin3
    people:
    - peopl1
    - peopl2
    - peopl3

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```